# PDF of sum exponential random variable multiplied by constant.

Tags: summation, density-function, exponential-distribution

I am trying to find the PDF of $\gamma_m$ inthe following expression but getting stuck due to presence of summation and constant.

$\gamma_m = \sum_{i=1}^{R}k_i\cdot X_i$-----(1)

where, $X_i$ is i.i.d. exponential random variable and $k_i$ is the constant.

Any help pls....

Comment: What is the relevance of $m$ and $R$? Is $R=m$?

Comment: Also, do you know anything about the values of $k_i$? For specific values of $k_i$ you can use moment generating functions to solve this, but I don't there's a nice answer in general.

Comment: Thanks JackT for the quick response..... yes $R = m$..

Comment: Also the values of $K_i$ are same for each $i$...

Comment: In that case, if $X_i \sim \textrm{exp}(\lambda)$ then $\gamma_m$ is a Gamma distribution with parameters $m$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok... and pls let me know if my understanding is correct: The above expression (1) can further be written as $\gamma_m = K\sum_{i=1}^{R}X_i$ where $K$ is constant , related as $k_1 = k_2 = k_3 = k_4...= k_R = K$....

Comment: Yes if $k_i$ is the same for every $i$, you may set $k_i = k$ for all $i$ - see my answer. Also, I realised when I did the calculation that the parameters in my previous comment was slightly wrong - again see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$ \gamma_m = k\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ where $X_i \sim \exp (\lambda) $ are i.i.d. Consider the moment generating function $$ M_{\gamma_m}(t):= \mathbb{E} e^{t \gamma_m}.$$ Then \begin{align*}
M_{\gamma_m}(t) &= \mathbb{E} e^{tk \sum_{i=1}^n X_i} \\
&= \mathbb{E} \prod_{i=1}^m e^{tk X_i}.
\end{align*} Since $X_i$ are i.i.d., we are able to swap the product and the expected value. If $M(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{t X_i}$ then it follows $$M_{\gamma_m}(t) =  \prod_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}e^{t kX_i} = (M(kt))^m.  $$ It is well known that the moment generating function of an exponential distribution is $$M(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t} \qquad (t<\lambda). $$ Thus, $$M_{\gamma_m}(t) = \bigg ( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-kt}\bigg )^m\qquad (t<\frac \lambda k). $$ From inspection, this is the moment generating function of a $\Gamma(m,\lambda/k)$. Thus, $\gamma_m \sim \Gamma(m,\lambda/k)$.

**Remarks:** 1. If you don't assume $k_i = k$ then $$M_{\gamma_m}(t) = \prod_{i=1}^m\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-k_it}.$$ It is not altogether clear what distribution this corresponds to.

2. Some people might argue that this calculation is tautological since a $\Gamma(m,\lambda)$ r.v. is often *defined* to be the sum of $m$ i.i.d $\exp(\lambda)$ r.v's.